# Ionic ion-list swipe to delete class remains active

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I'm using ion-list with `can-swipe` and `show-delete` everything works fine, up until it comes to actually deleting the item in the list,

for example, if I have an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I swipe to delete `3` and delete it, it then disappears and is removed from the list however the `swiped` class remains active on the element below in the list, in this case it then shows the delete option for `4` -- Is anyone aware of how we can get the class to not pass on to the element below it?

Answer (score 2):

In my particular situation the standard fix to this is not possible, due to an issue in cordova when it comes to displaying two "delete buttons"
because of this I have a function that handled removing an item from the array of items, I programatically closed all options buttons by calling `$ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();`, hopefully this helps someone else, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue but I edited an example from Ionic official codepens:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.data = {
    showDelete: false
  };
  
  $scope.edit = function(item) {
    alert('Edit Item: ' + item.id);
  };
  $scope.share = function(item) {
    alert('Share Item: ' + item.id);
  };
  
  $scope.moveItem = function(item, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
  };
  
  $scope.onItemDelete = function(item) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
  };
  
  $scope.items = [
    { id: 0 },
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 }
  ];
  
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Ionic List Directive</title>
   
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-minus-outline"
          ng-click="data.showDelete = !data.showDelete; data.showReorder = false"></button>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Delete/Option Buttons</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" ng-click="data.showDelete = false; data.showReorder = !data.showReorder">
            Reorder
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>

      <!-- The list directive is great, but be sure to also checkout the collection repeat directive when scrolling through large lists -->
      
      <ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete" show-reorder="data.showReorder">

        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
                  item="item"
                  href="#/item/{{item.id}}" class="item-remove-animate">
          Item {{ item.id }}
          <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" 
                             ng-click="onItemDelete(item)">
          </ion-delete-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                             ng-click="edit(item)">
            Edit
          </ion-option-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                             ng-click="onItemDelete(item)">
            Del
          </ion-option-button>
          <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, my issue was a bit more complex and it turns out it was due to having multiple delete options

Comment: In order to let understand your issue you have to provide complete info and possibly a replicable example...

Comment: Oh I will do, don't worry ;)